# scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake is not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I have 5 `UITextField`s in a `UIScrollView` and when I touch the 4th textfield the keyboard appears, but it  appears over the textfield (the textfield remains below the keyboard) and I can not see what I am typing.

I tried to use `-scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake` shifted the `contentSize` size, and it is working fine.

But the behaviour is not understandable. Can anyone tell me how this function actually works?

Comment: not understandable? you mean the code isn't clear to read?

Comment: you need to set your frame when your textField is select.

Comment: @iPatel yes i am setting the frame.. an all the textfields goes up and the partcular text field is visible. but when i gain want the original frame.. it is not working as expected.. actually the get shifted much below

Comment: set contentOffset property such that it becomes to top.

Comment: @Wain scrollRectToVisibe is not working as expected.

Comment: @santhu i am using this line to shift up the the contents of scroll view: [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 21, 320, 269) animated:YES]; Then should i set the contentOffSet property. What does this property actually means? what does it set?

Comment: i once had the same issue, scrollRect to visible is not woking. so i used contentOffset.It just like padding from top. test it by puting some random values to it.

Comment: @SaurabhGulia : Have you set the delegate for the TextField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect rc = [textField bounds];
    rc = [textField convertRect:rc toView:self.scrollView];
    CGPoint pt = rc.origin;
    pt.x = 0;
    if(rc.origin.y > 200) // here you can also change value 200 and 150 as per your requirement.
        pt.y -=  150;
    else
        pt.y -= rc.origin.y;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thanks.. problem solved using -setContentOffset method

Comment: it helped me, however if you can describle about hard coded 200 and -150, it will be more helpful.

Comment: welcome-- Also you can change it as per your requirement..  :)